# Array with multiple columns formatting

Tags: python, arrays

I have multiple arrays and I would like to combine them together so when I call a row, the 1st value of each array is shown. How can I do this?

```
array1 = ['happy','sad','tired']
array2 = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes']
array3 = ['monkeys','elephants','tigers']

array = [array1,array2,array3]

output:['happy','sad','tired'],['oranges','apples','grapes']etc...

wanted output: ['happy','oranges','monkeys'],['sad','apples','elephants']etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use numpy? That would make things very simple.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = ['happy','sad','tired']
array2 = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes']
array3 = ['monkeys','elephants','tigers']

array = np.array([array1,array2,array3]).reshape(3, -1)
```

Then you can access either rows or columns with indexing:

```
# column
array[:, 0]
# Out[224]: array(['happy', 'oranges', 'monkeys'], dtype='<U9')

# row
array[0, :]
# Out[224]: array(['happy', 'sad', 'tired'], dtype='<U9')
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about np.array

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could do it is with zip() and list comprehension to add the elements to their own list within the largest list object

```
output = [[item1,item2,item3] for item1,item2,item3 in zip(array1, array2, array3)]
print(output)
```

though this assumes that the lists are of equal length.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I have a lot of data being processed and it has a slight delay

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is take the transpose of the `array` you obtained in line 4.

```
array1 = ['happy','sad','tired']
array2 = ['oranges', 'apples', 'grapes']
array3 = ['monkeys','elephants','tigers']

array = [array1, array2, array3]
# take the transpose
transpose_array = list(map(lambda x:list(x), zip(*array)))

print(transpose_array)
```

Here, using `zip(*array)` simply gives the transpose of the `array` as a list of tuples. Therefore here I use a lambda function to convert each tuple to a list so that we obtained a list of tuples.